# jquery - identify items by class and then extract value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following hidden input field on my form:

```
 <input class="dow" id="hidden_dow0" type="hidden" value="m,t,w,r,f,s,n">
```

Once the form has loaded I need to find this hidden control, extract the value... and then use each item in the list ('m,t,w ') to set corresponding checkboxes on

So far, I have been able to find all hidden inputs, but I don't know how to extract the value from it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$('.dow ').each(function (i, row) {
        var $row = $(row);  
        var $ext = $row.find('input[value*=""]');
        console.log($ext.val);  //fails.
    });
```

**EDIT 1**

This is I tried:

```
//find all items that have class "dow" ... and 
$('.dow ').each(function (i, row) {
    var $row = $(row);
    console.log(i);
    console.log(row); //prints the <input> control
    //var $ext = $row.find('input[value*=""]');
    var $ext = $row.find('input[type="hidden"]');
    console.log($ext); //prints an object
    $ext.each(function() {
        console.log( $(this).val() );  //does not work
    });
});
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of the issue you are facing. This means we need HTML. You can use Stack Snippets (icon with `<>` on a page) to try constructing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery `val()` is a function.
The `.dow` element **is** the input, you don't need to find it

```
$('.dow ').each(function (i, row) {
    console.log( $(this).val() );  //works
});
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me.  nothing prints in the console.

Comment: @Happydevdays - my bad, got confused from your use of `row` and `find()` and assumed you had different HTML, but `.dow` is the class given to the input, so if they all have that class, all you need is `$('.dow')`, and if you want something else, you're going to have to explain it better, or post some HTML